# Find top n closest places

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am using this simple correlated sub-query to find the closest place to a place (example simplified of course):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    FromPlaceId INT NOT NULL,
    FromPlaceName [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    ToPlaceId INT NOT NULL,
    ToPlaceName [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    Distance FLOAT NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO #Temp( FromPlaceId, FromPlaceName, ToPlaceId, ToPlaceName, Distance) VALUES ( 1, N'Place1' , 2 , N'Place2' , 1.0  )
INSERT INTO #Temp( FromPlaceId, FromPlaceName, ToPlaceId, ToPlaceName, Distance) VALUES ( 1, N'Place1' , 3 , N'Place3' , 2.0  )
INSERT INTO #Temp( FromPlaceId, FromPlaceName, ToPlaceId, ToPlaceName, Distance) VALUES ( 2, N'Place2' , 1 , N'Place1' , 1.0  )
INSERT INTO #Temp( FromPlaceId, FromPlaceName, ToPlaceId, ToPlaceName, Distance) VALUES ( 2, N'Place2' , 3 , N'Place3' , 13.0  )
INSERT INTO #Temp( FromPlaceId, FromPlaceName, ToPlaceId, ToPlaceName, Distance) VALUES ( 3, N'Place3' , 1 , N'Place1' , 2.0  )
INSERT INTO #Temp( FromPlaceId, FromPlaceName, ToPlaceId, ToPlaceName, Distance) VALUES ( 3, N'Place3' , 2 , N'Place2' , 13.0  )

SELECT * FROM #Temp

SELECT 
    a.FromPlaceId,
    a.FromPlaceName,
    a.ToPlaceId,
    a.ToPlaceName,
    a.Distance
FROM #temp AS a WHERE a.Distance = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 b.Distance FROM #Temp AS b WHERE a.FromPlaceId = b.FromPlaceId
    ORDER BY b.Distance ASC
)
```

I am just wondering how to get the 2 or 3 closest places. Obviously, a correlated sub query does not work in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement right I think you should be able use the `rank()` window function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
       FromPlaceId,
       FromPlaceName,
       ToPlaceId,
       ToPlaceName,
       Distance,
       rank = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FromPlaceId ORDER BY Distance)
    FROM #temp  
) a
WHERE rank <= 2;
```

This would return all the ToPlaceId for each FromPlaceId that have a distance that is in the top two closest, so if several ToPlaceId have the same distance all would be returned.

Changing your current query to use `in` and `top 2` in the correlated query should also work, although I think the window function might perform better.

```
FROM #temp AS a WHERE a.Distance IN
(
    SELECT TOP 2 b.Distance
```

Comment: I like the rank over approach - tried something similar but failed so far - great stuff will try now!

Comment: Just an additional remark to help the OP see their options: RANK() might return less rows in case of ties, DENSE_RANK() could return more rows in such a case, and ROW_NUMBER() would return the number wanted by only returning some of the tying records and others not. So ROW_NUMBER() equals TOP n here, and DENSE_RANK() equals TOP n WITH TIES.